# JIT Spacetree Node Spacing Issue

Tags: spacing, infovis, thejit, space-tree

I've having an issue with JIT Spacetree where the nodes are being space massively far apart resulting in an unusable view. The first few nodes are fine but as you navigate deeper into the tree the spacing on the child nodes increases.

I'm using a pretty vanilla config very similar to example 1 on the JIT site
http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example1.html

Here's a screenshot that show a snippet but the problem is even worse than this shows as the spacing increases even further with additional nodes.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5454906/spacetree_issue.png

I've used this successfully for a while but never come across this particular issue.

Has anyone any ideas / thoughts?

Thanks

Neil

Here's an example JSON set that's generated.

```
{
"id": "Class91240",
"name": "Cube Org - OrgID",
"data": {"nodeType": "reportObj"},
"children": [{
    "id": "001",
    "name": "Data Warehouse - Org",
    "data": {"nodeType": "dataRep"},
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "002",
            "name": "DataWarehouse Loader - Update Org Data",
            "data": {"nodeType": "interface"},
            "children": [{
                "id": "003",
                "name": "Staging Database - MasterOrg",
                "data": {"nodeType": "dataRep"},
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "Class90189",
                        "name": "Staging Interface - Update Master Org Data",
                        "data": {"nodeType": "interface"},
                        "children": [{
                            "id": "Class91838",
                            "name": "Staging Database - ExtractABC",
                            "data": {"nodeType": "dataRep"},
                            "children": [{
                                "id": "Class93632",
                                "name": "Staging Interface - Rates Data",
                                "data": {"nodeType": "busLogic"},
                                "children": [{
                                    "id": "Class90125",
                                    "name": "Operational Data Stored Procedures - Data",
                                    "data": {"nodeType": "interface"},
                                    "children": [{
                                        "id": "Class90387",
                                        "name": "sim_xyz_rates",
                                        "data": {"nodeType": "feed"},
                                        "children": []
                                    }]
                                }]
                            }]
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "Class90340",
                        "name": "Staging Interface - Update  Master tables Budget Data",
                        "data": {"nodeType": "interface"},
                        "children": [{
                            "id": "Class91889",
                            "name": "Staging Database - ExtractPQR_Fact01",
                            "data": {"nodeType": "dataRep"},
                            "children": [{
                                "id": "Class90308",
                                "name": "Web UI Interface - Export Template Data",
                                "data": {"nodeType": "interface"},
                                "children": [{
                                    "id": "Class91942",
                                    "name": "HTC Staging Database - DEF_Template",
                                    "data": {"nodeType": "dataRep"},
                                    "children": []
                                }]
                            }]
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "Class90342",
                        "name": "Staging Interface - Update  Master tables Forecast Data",
                        "data": {"nodeType": "interface"},
                        "children": [{
                            "id": "Class91889",
                            "name": "Staging Database - ExtractPQR_Fact01",
                            "data": {"nodeType": "dataRep"},
                            "children": [{
                                "id": "Class90308",
                                "name": "Web UI Interface - Export Template Data",
                                "data": {"nodeType": "interface"},
                                "children": [{
                                    "id": "Class91942",
                                    "name": "HTC Staging Database - DEF_Template",
                                    "data": {"nodeType": "dataRep"},
                                    "children": []
                                }]
                            }]
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            }]
        },
        {
            "id": "Class90324",
            "name": "DataWarehouse Loader - Update  Discovery  Tables Budget Data",
            "data": {"nodeType": "interface"},
            "children": [{
                "id": "003",
                "name": "Staging Database - MasterOrg",
                "data": {"nodeType": "dataRep"},
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "Class90189",
                        "name": "Staging Interface - Update Master Org Data",
                        "data": {"nodeType": "interface"},
                        "children": [{
                            "id": "Class91838",
                            "name": "Staging Database - ExtractABC",
                            "data": {"nodeType": "dataRep"},
                            "children": [{
                                "id": "Class93632",
                                "name": "Staging Interface - Rates Data",
                                "data": {"nodeType": "busLogic"},
                                "children": [{
                                    "id": "Class90125",
                                    "name": "Operational Data Stored Procedures - Data",
                                    "data": {"nodeType": "interface"},
                                    "children": [{
                                        "id": "Class90387",
                                        "name": "sim_xyz_rates",
                                        "data": {"nodeType": "feed"},
                                        "children": []
                                    }]
                                }]
                            }]
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "Class90340",
                        "name": "Staging Interface - Update  Master tables Budget Data",
                        "data": {"nodeType": "interface"},
                        "children": [{
                            "id": "Class91889",
                            "name": "Staging Database - ExtractPQR_Fact01",
                            "data": {"nodeType": "dataRep"},
                            "children": [{
                                "id": "Class90308",
                                "name": "Web UI Interface - Export Template Data",
                                "data": {"nodeType": "interface"},
                                "children": [{
                                    "id": "Class91942",
                                    "name": "HTC Staging Database - DEF_Template",
                                    "data": {"nodeType": "dataRep"},
                                    "children": []
                                }]
                            }]
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "Class90342",
                        "name": "Staging Interface - Update  Master tables Forecast Data",
                        "data": {"nodeType": "interface"},
                        "children": [{
                            "id": "Class91889",
                            "name": "Staging Database - ExtractPQR_Fact01",
                            "data": {"nodeType": "dataRep"},
                            "children": [{
                                "id": "Class90308",
                                "name": "Web UI Interface - Export Template Data",
                                "data": {"nodeType": "interface"},
                                "children": [{
                                    "id": "Class91942",
                                    "name": "HTC Staging Database - DEF_Template",
                                    "data": {"nodeType": "dataRep"},
                                    "children": []
                                }]
                            }]
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            }]
        },
        {
            "id": "Class90331",
            "name": "DataWarehouse Loader - Update  Discovery Tables Forecast Data",
            "data": {"nodeType": "interface"},
            "children": [{
                "id": "003",
                "name": "Staging Database - MasterOrg",
                "data": {"nodeType": "dataRep"},
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "Class90189",
                        "name": "Staging Interface - Update Master Org Data",
                        "data": {"nodeType": "interface"},
                        "children": [{
                            "id": "Class91838",
                            "name": "Staging Database - ExtractABC",
                            "data": {"nodeType": "dataRep"},
                            "children": [{
                                "id": "Class93632",
                                "name": "Staging Interface - Rates Data",
                                "data": {"nodeType": "busLogic"},
                                "children": [{
                                    "id": "Class90125",
                                    "name": "Operational Data Stored Procedures - Data",
                                    "data": {"nodeType": "interface"},
                                    "children": [{
                                        "id": "Class90387",
                                        "name": "sim_xyz_rates",
                                        "data": {"nodeType": "feed"},
                                        "children": []
                                    }]
                                }]
                            }]
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "Class90340",
                        "name": "Staging Interface - Update  Master tables Budget Data",
                        "data": {"nodeType": "interface"},
                        "children": [{
                            "id": "Class91889",
                            "name": "Staging Database - ExtractPQR_Fact01",
                            "data": {"nodeType": "dataRep"},
                            "children": [{
                                "id": "Class90308",
                                "name": "Web UI Interface - Export Template Data",
                                "data": {"nodeType": "interface"},
                                "children": [{
                                    "id": "Class91942",
                                    "name": "HTC Staging Database - DEF_Template",
                                    "data": {"nodeType": "dataRep"},
                                    "children": []
                                }]
                            }]
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "Class90342",
                        "name": "Staging Interface - Update  Master tables Forecast Data",
                        "data": {"nodeType": "interface"},
                        "children": [{
                            "id": "Class91889",
                            "name": "Staging Database - ExtractPQR_Fact01",
                            "data": {"nodeType": "dataRep"},
                            "children": [{
                                "id": "Class90308",
                                "name": "Web UI Interface - Export Template Data",
                                "data": {"nodeType": "interface"},
                                "children": [{
                                    "id": "Class91942",
                                    "name": "HTC Staging Database - DEF_Template",
                                    "data": {"nodeType": "dataRep"},
                                    "children": []
                                }]
                            }]
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            }]
        }
    ]
}]
```

}

Comment: The google group for JIT is quite strong and you can try there too to get some good useful suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the cause of your issue, but you have duplicate nodes in your json structure.  Id's must be unique with SpaceTrees in JIT